# Add folder as place in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've tried looking for a solution online but I could only find some where I have to change a reg key. For me those do not exists. The paths are:

HCU > Software > Microsoft > Office > Common > Cloud Storage

And some other regkey. I would like to add a folder instead of e.x a OneDrive Location. Here is a picture of where I would like to see the folder name: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebe7Q.jpg

e.x on the image you see This PC. Now I would like to have 10 of those in that list but with folder icon ofcourse.

I know I can set a default path but then I have to browse to other files if they are not in the default path. I also know I can drag them to my favorites and then add that folder as default path but then I still have to click browse > foldername and then save.

Because I'm working with so many files it would save a lot of clicks if I didn't have to click browse first but directly see the folders listed under browse.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Click on options -> save
Then, uncheck
1.Don't show the backstage when opening or saving file
2. show additional places...
3.Save to Computer by default

In the default local file location,provide your desired location and click OK

Now if you will double click on the Computer icon for opening or saving file it will open your desired location by default.

Enjoy

Comment: This is not really what I want. I have to save files intensifly at 10 different locations on the computer (not all in one folder and all different files). I would like something that looks like browse but then with a folder name. You could say I want to have 10 different. I'm sorry for the confusion I'll update my answer to be more clear.